# how to get count of record using anonymous code

Tags: apex, soql, query, execute-anonymous

I am trying to get the count of records where field `value!=null` using anonymous code.

```
list<string> lstfields=new list<string>();
lstfields.add(Account_Manager__c);
lstfields.add(Contact_Count__c);
for(integer i=0;i<=lstfields.size();i++)
{
   system.debug([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE lstfields[i]!=null]);
}
```

Below is my code which is not working.
Please suggest

Comment: Why don't you use `[SELECT Count() FROM Account WHERE Account_Manager__c! = null AND Contact_Count__c != null]` and avoid soql inside for loop.

Comment: Actually i want to fetch record count of 500 fields ,so i will use 100 fields each time in list ,i will iterate it and then next 100 field .to avoid manual work

Comment: Keep in mind there is [limits for number of characters in soql](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
list<string> lstfields=new list<string>();
lstfields.add(Account_Manager__c);
lstfields.add(Contact_Count__c);
for(integer i=0;i<=lstfields.size();i++)
{
    system.debug(Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE '+lstfields[i]+'!=null').size());
}
```

system.debug(**Database.query**('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE '+lstfields[i]+'!=null').**size()**);

Comment: Getting Error:Line: 6, Column: 62
unexpected token: '[

Comment: I corrected my answer, to use a dynamic field name you need to use a dynamic SOQL by using the Database.Query method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data about field usage, I suggest you install **`Field Trip`** (free AppExchange package). I have no affiliation but have used it successfully in the past for this sort of task and it seems the right tool for the job in this case.

> ## [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4)
>
> Run reports on standard and custom field usage.
>
> **App by Qandor**
> Ever wish you could run reports on the fields you have in salesforce? Take a Field Trip! This utility lets you analyze the fields of any object, including what percentage of the records (or a subset of your records) have that field populated.